# Google Analytics V4: get all events for each session

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get all events for each session ?

Exemple:

session1:
- event1
- event2
- event3

session2
- event1
- event2

Thanks for your help !

Comment: There is no session Id dimension I doubt it.

Comment: There is no dimension called sessionId. But if you have premium account then you can see all the events in BigQuery by integrating it with your GA profile.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. I will see the premium version.